# No Module named QtMultimedia

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

Trying to play audio in a qt gui

I've tried basically every suggestion on Google pertaining to playing audio with pyqt (pyside, pygame, QtMultimedia). It seems pretty straight forward using QSound, but it doesn't work for me for some reason

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *

ImportError: No module named QtMultimedia
```

Everything else works but the multimedia module

Comment: How have you installed PyQt5? What is your OS?